# ("print"), ("int" not subscritble), variables and list's syntax in this code

Tags: python

There's been "print", ("int" not subscritable) syntax, and so on in this code. The program that I've been trying to do is

> Write a program that asks the user to enter how many numbers are to be averaged. The user can then enter the numbers. The program outputs the total and the mean.

I've tried `for i in range`, lists and both of them always end up in ("int" not subscriptible) or ("print" syntax's). Here's the code:

```
x = []
for i in range (2):
  x = int(input("enter a number: "))

for i in range (1):
  Sum = (int(x[0]) + (int(x[1]))

for i in range (1):
         Mean = Sum/2

print ((int(x[0]), "+", (int(x[1])), end = "=", Sum))
print ((int(x[0]), "+", (int(x[1])), end = "=", Sum,"/2 =", Mean))
```

Expect the mean and the sum.

Comment: Don't just describe the approximate error, give a [mcve] with proper formatting.

Comment: `x = []` does not do anything because x gets rewritten to an int here `x = int(input("enter a number: "))` . When you get to the print statement, x is an `int`, and so `x[0]` is an error.

Comment: Also, `for i in range (1):` is the equivalent of "do the following one time". It can be eliminated.

Comment: As there are almost as many errors as lines here, voting to close as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are first assigning an empty list to x:

```
x = []
```

And then you assign a single int (twice):

```
for i in range (2):
    x = int(input("enter a number: "))
```

> 1: x = []
>
> 2: x = first user input
>
> 3: x = second user input

What you want to do is append the user input to the list in x.

Either like this:

```
x.append(int(input("enter a number: ")))
```

Or like this:

```
x += [int(input("enter a number: "))]
```

The `[]` in the second example are required to add (`+`) lists together as you can not add a list and a value but you can add two lists in terms of appending one to the  other.

You could also use list comprehension:

```
x = [int(input("enter a number: ")) for i in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Built-in function [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to get the sum of elements in a list.

```
x=[int(input("enter a number: ")) for count in range(2)]
print (x[0], "+", x[1],"=", sum(x))
print (x[0], "+", x[1],"=", sum(x),"/2 =", sum(x)/2)
```

Output

```
enter a number: 23
enter a number: 43
23 + 43 = 66
23 + 43 = 66 /2 = 33.0
```